# IP address from LAN side of client router appears in NAT table of primary router

Tags: router, ip, lan, nat

I’m seeing what appears to be strange activity on my Primary router (the only router connected to the ISP modem) from one Android device. It could be that I’ve never seen it before as the day is nearing end and most everybody else is gone and this one maintenance person is the only other person on the network. However, what I’m seeing doesn’t make sense to me in the context of what NAT is supposed to do for client devices, at least as I understand it. This is my first time looking at a NAT table mind you.

So, I had some problems this morning making a connection to a device connected the primary router (through the primary switch to another switch.) I had to restart the router and switch. After everything was done for the day I had to do the same thing again to power off the device. This is what led me to look at the NAT table on the primary router to look for some clue as to what caused the temporary interruption. The primary router is DD-WRT modified and I was able to telnet into it and cat the table.

I found a foreign private IP address in the table! The primary router has a LAN-side address range of `192.168.1.1/255`. I have two other routers (5 actually but only two others were involved in this activity) connected to the primary switch and have a LAN-side address of `192.168.2.1/255` and `192.168.4.1/255`. The first time around I found `192.168.2.108`! I logged on to the remote admin page of the router and found it was assigned to an Android phone connected wirelessly. I blocked the MAC address of the phone and waited to see who it was (when they come to me to complain about connecting.) Waited an hour and nobody complained.

Later on I checked again and found another foreign IP address but this time it was `192.168.4.30`! So I logged on to the router that IP address comes from and found it was from the same Android phone. I remembered that the maintenance guy has an Android phone so I asked him directly and found that indeed it was his phone.

The first time I spotted it, it was a connection to an IP address in China. The second time it was a connection to an Amazon EC2 server. I didn’t record the first instance but I have the second one still:

```
tcp      6 1096 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.4.30 dst=23.21.225.144 sport=53993 dport=443 packets=9 bytes=1131 [UNREPLIED] src=23.21.225.144 dst=192.168.4.30 sport=443 dport=53993 packets=0 bytes=0 mark=0 use=2
```

Remember, this entry came from a DD-WRT modified router with a LAN-side IP address range of `192.168.1.1/255`.

Is this rare but normal activity or does this possibly indicate a compromised Android phone?

**Edit:**
The network topology is fairly straightforward. The primary router is the only router connected to the ISP modem with NAT and DHCP enabled and is DD-WRT modded, for various reasons. All other routers also have NAT and DHCP enabled (with their own subnets for various reasons) and are connected (via a main switch) to the primary router. There are no triple NATs. All of the routers are non-commercial off-the-shelf (residential) grade. When I show an `IP/255`, I'm referring to the default Class C subnet for LAN-side private IP address ranges; ie `192.168.1.1/255`=`192.168.1.1-192.168.1.255`. Sorry for any confusion, my network terminology and notation is outdated.

Comment: Your router is NATting internal addresses to the public address of the router as they access the internet.  This is normal behaviour, you will always see private addresses in the NAT table under normal circumstances.

Comment: @Paul  Surely he knows that. But he's asking a question about 2 NAT routers.  So if you were to address what he's writing about, your comment would surely have to be a bit more involved

Comment: you should clarify re foreign. There's A)foreign to the range of the NAT router B)the IP establishing connection to foreign websites.. C)An IP that none of your devices have, is on your network

Comment: @barlop If the NAT table on R1 is showing addresses from the other routers, then he is not using NAT on those routers, and his question also does not suggest he is using NAT anywhere other than the perimeter.

Comment: It's hard to give you a useful answer without some information about how your routers are connected to each other. For example, which routers are suppose to be doing NAT? Which routers treat their default route target as a WAN connection?

Comment: @Paul  It looks like he was trying to suggest that his routers had different LAN side addresses, different ranges..(which suggests and perhaps would imply double/triple NAT), though he made a nonsense of the subnet masks when he tried to say that.  And if the IP addresses of a wireless device shows in the NAT table of the one router running NAT, and is within its range of IP Addresses, then it's not much of a question.  I figure he was talking about LAN IP address ranges for a reason.

Comment: @barlop The routers have different LAN side addresses, they have to, but this doesn't imply any use of NAT (though admittedly when people do this they tend to leave NAT on through misunderstanding routing).  If the IP addresses of the other subnets are appearing in the NAT table of R1 then it is because the OP has it set up *correctly* (assuming multiple subnets are a design decision rather than another misunderstanding about L2/L3.  DD-WRT means the OP can do static routes,

Comment: @Paul *obviously* the routers have different IP addresses.  I made the point that he referred to LAN side address  **range** and **ranges**   which suggests that he might be suggesting each doing DHCP, which tends to be done with NAT. And different ***RANGES** suggests he's talking about different subnets, which also implies double/triple NAT.  Are you saying that with DDWRT you can have multiple subnets without double/triple NAT? That's good.  BTW, when u do that with DDWRT, does each router interface have an IP? Or is DDWRT really setting up a VLAN Switch separating by groups of switch port?

Comment: @barlop Lots of routers can do DHCP without NAT, even cheap domestic routers.  This is the common misunderstanding I was referring to. You still have a different IP on the WAN interface to the range on the LAN side, you just don't nat one to the other.  Instead you route back from the next hop.

Comment: @Paul if no NAT is taking place, then the device isn't changing the src/dest IPs in the packet, and the LAN side is going to be  be public.  So if he has more than one comp, he'd need more than one IP from his ISP, and that is not that common.  And as for multiple subnets LAN side, I am not sure that most consumer routers allow for it.. they just have 2 subnets, one WAN with its one IP and one LAN. For example, Netgear WNDR4500/N900  $90 not refurbished(so not even that cheap), and AFAIK doesn't support multiple subnets LAN side.

Comment: @barlop Only the primary is connected to the internet, and the rest are connected to it, from what I can tell.  Then the primary can do NAT for all the others so only a  single public IP is needed.  What I am describing is the most likely set-up given the behaviour described, and perfectly achievable by dd-wrt (and domestics I have used).  If I was setting this up, and the subnets were actually needed, then this is how I would do it - it is the right approach.

Comment: @Paul  A)are you talking about multiple subnets LAN side, or not?   B)Are you talking about the non primary routers, doing DHCP(and thus perhaps clashing with the primary router), or not?   C)If all you are saying is that (perhaps ddwrt aside) consumer routers can only support ONE subnet LAN side, then I know that that's what i'm telling you as well. The next step up, which can support multiple subnets LAN side, is a VLAN Switch routing between subnets or groups of port, and even netgear(last time I checked) only make two such devices in their consumer range.

Comment: @barlop  The OP has multiple routers.  There are multiple subnets because there are multiple LAN sides - there are 5 in all.  They are all doing DHCP for their subnet.  There are no clashes.  I am simply saying that there is only one place where NAT is happening, from the description, and that is on the router facing the internet.  The other routers are all connected to this one.

Answer (score 0):

This must be rogue activity on your LAN.

Your X.X.X.X/255 makes no sense - that is not a valid netmask - Getting the correct netmask set on your router is the first step to reducing the space the rogue device can work with.

The second step is to look at the ARP table (arp -an) and find the list of IP addresses which are unrecognised.  You can take the first 3 octets of these addresses [and do a lookup](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/) which, if the activity is innocent, may help you narrow down the device you are looking for by telling you the manufacturer - note that this can easily be faked sometimes, so if its malicious it might not tell you much.

You can also use tcpdump (for example tcpdump -n -i eth0 src or dst 192.168.4.30) to show, in real time what that device is communicating with.

Comment: When I wrote X.X.X.X/255 I meant X.X.X.X/24.  Forgot about CIDR notation.  Sorry for the confusion.